# Text over image gets hidden when a filter is applied to the image

Tags: html, css

In the example below the text in the h1 element is hidden when the filter is applied to the image, and visible when the filter is disabled or turned off (set to none, or deleted the css applied to img tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    .item {
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
    }
    h1 {
        height: auto;
        font-size: 30px;
        color:white;
        margin-top: -50%;
    }
    img {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    img:hover {
        -webkit-filter: none;
        -moz-filter: none;
        -ms-filter: none;
        -o-filter: none;
        filter: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="image.jpg" height="500" />
        <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's happen, but you can fixed this bug with add `position` property to your `h1`

css :

```
h1 {
    position:relative;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#000;
    margin-top: -50%;
}
```

and think to change `img:hover` by `.item:hover img` for have hover even when you hover h1

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3MvU/4/**

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with Z-index as it works without it. - http://jsfiddle.net/Z3MvU/3/ It's the positioning context that seems to be the issue so that might be it.

Comment: So it's just position:relative; when you remove it it's doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I thinks so, either way, it's probably a good idea to reinforce the 'stacking order` +1

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `margin-top` and add:

```
position: relative;
top: -50%;
```

To h1 it displays as you want.